# Removing Push Topic in Uninstall Script of Managed Package

Tags: apex, managed-package

Our managed package creates a push topic in the subscriber org as part of our use case. We need to remove this push topic on uninstall of the package. Can we perform delete operation on the push topic in the uninstall script of the managed package?

Comment: I don't see why not, though I suspect consumers need to unregister from the channel first.

Comment: Thanks I think that could be it why I am not able to delete the push topic.